# Compute pandas n_group in polars and assign new id

Tags: python-polars

I am looking for the best way to do pandas' `df.groupby(["group_a", "group_b"]).ngroup()`in polars and assign that specific ngroup counter value back to the respective group.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
     {"group_a": ["a", "aa", "a"], "group_b": ["b", "bb", "b"], "val": [1, 2, 3]}
)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ group_a ┆ group_b ┆ val │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ i64 │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ aa      ┆ bb      ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 3   │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────┘
```

should become

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ group_a ┆ group_b ┆ val ┆ new_group │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 1   ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ aa      ┆ bb      ┆ 2   ┆ 1         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 3   ┆ 0         │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

In pandas, I would use ngroups to do this with a join, but don't know in polars.

Edit:
I have found one possible workaround but I feel like there should be a better, more efficient way, since it also gets killed for my actual dataset of millions of rows.

```
group_ids = ["group_a", "group_b"]
df = df.join(
     pl.concat([
        df.unique(subset=group_ids),
        (pl.arange(0, len(df.unique(subset=group_ids)), eager=True, dtype=pl.Int64)
        .alias("new_id")
        .to_frame())], how="horizontal")
        .select(group_ids + ["new_id"]), left_on=group_ids, right_on=group_ids
)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, shouldn't pandas version be `df.groupby(["a", "b"]).ngroup()`?

Comment: It was meant as a generic example, sorry. I have edited it to make it more explicit for the toy problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** `.rank(method="dense")` appears to be the builtin way to generate sequential ids.

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({
...    "group_a": ["a", "aa", "a", "aaa"], 
...    "group_b": ["b", "bb", "b", "bbb"], 
...    "val": [1, 2, 3, 4] 
... })
...
... group_ids = ["group_a", "group_b"]
...
... (
...    df
...    .with_row_count(name="new_id")
...    .with_column(
...       pl.col("new_id")
...         .first()
...         .over(group_ids)
...         .rank(method="dense") - 1
...    )
... )
shape: (4, 4)
┌────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ new_id | group_a | group_b | val │
│ ---    | ---     | ---     | --- │
│ u32    | str     | str     | i64 │
╞════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ 0      | a       | b       | 1   │
├────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 1      | aa      | bb      | 2   │
├────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 0      | a       | b       | 3   │
├────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 2      | aaa     | bbb     | 4   │
└─//─────┴─//──────┴─//──────┴─//──┘
```

---

**Explanation:**

We first generate the non-sequential group numbers

```
>>> (
...    df
...    .with_row_count(name="new_id")
...    .with_column(pl.col("new_id").first().over(group_ids))
... )
shape: (4, 4)
┌────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ new_id | group_a | group_b | val │
│ ---    | ---     | ---     | --- │
│ u32    | str     | str     | i64 │
╞════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ 0      | a       | b       | 1   │
├────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 1      | aa      | bb      | 2   │
├────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 0      | a       | b       | 3   │
├────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────┤
│ 3      | aaa     | bbb     | 4   │
└─//─────┴─//──────┴─//──────┴─//──┘
```

`.rank(method="dense")` generates sequential numbers starting from `1`

Comment: Thank you, however, I get some weird results if there are more than 2 distinct groups. For example, `with df = pl.DataFrame(
     {"group_a": ["a", "aa", "a", "aaa"], "group_b": ["b", "bb", "b", "bbb"], "val": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
    )` I see 0, 1, 0, 3 in the resulting `row_nr` but I would only expect 0, 1, 2 because there are only three distinct groups.

Comment: Ah right - I've added an answer using `.groupby()` + `.explode()` - feels like there should be way to do it similar to per group count [using .cumcount()](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2542#issuecomment-1033723861) though.

Comment: @nleh I believe I figured out how to fix the `.with_column()` method. I removed the groupby/explode approach as it was slower.

Comment: @nleh I just learned about `.rank(method="dense")` - using that appears to be much more efficient than the previous attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that will keep your group id's consecutive.

```py
groupby_vars = "group_a", "group_b"
(
    df.join(
        df.select(groupby_vars).unique().with_row_count(name="group_id"),
        on=groupby_vars,
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ group_a ┆ group_b ┆ val ┆ group_id │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ i64 ┆ u32      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 1   ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ aa      ┆ bb      ┆ 2   ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 3   ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ aaa     ┆ bbb     ┆ 4   ┆ 2        │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. I found your answer to perform (much) faster than @jqurius answer, however, on larger dataset, (~200million rows) this gets killed, while the other approach does not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are thinking of joining a groupby result back to the original `DataFrame`, polars window functions are almost always the answer.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group_a": ["a", "aa", "a"], 
    "group_b": ["b", "bb", "b"], "val": [1, 2, 3]
})

(df
 .with_column(pl.arange(0, pl.count()).alias("new_group"))
 .with_column(
    pl.first("new_group").over(["group_a", "group_b"])
))
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ group_a ┆ group_b ┆ val ┆ new_group │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 1   ┆ 0         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ aa      ┆ bb      ┆ 2   ┆ 1         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a       ┆ b       ┆ 3   ┆ 0         │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: With the input mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74600568/compute-pandas-n-group-in-polars-and-assign-new-id#comment131688420_74603070 it generates non-consecutive IDs. Is there a way to generate consecutive IDs without the need for the `.is_first().cumsum().over()` approach in that answer? Thank you.

Comment: It appears `.rank(method="dense")` was what I was looking for ...